# how to copy image and text to clipboard using Java?

Tags: java

i want to copy image and text together to clipboard at same time
but i can copy image or text

```
//class to copy text
    StringSelection selection=new StringSelection(text);

 c.setContents(selection, null);
//class to copy image
                   ImageTransferable s=new ImageTransferable(image);


                       c.setContents(s, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a custom Transferable object:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/345580/GUI/java/Cut-copying-pasting-custom-object