# How to copy images and text to clipboard at the same time

Tags: java, clipboard

i need to copy a `Image` object and a `String` object to clipboard like this:[Paste pictures and text at the same time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFEHT.png), but i can only copy texts or images.

i have already read [how to copy image and text to clipboard using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091178) and http://www.coderanch.com/t/345580/GUI/java/Cut-copying-pasting-custom-object, but it did not solve my problem.

by search on google, i only got the following code:

```
public class ClipboardTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        Image image = ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\文件\\java\\BParser\\src\\test\\java\\icon.png"));
        String text = "Hello world";
        Transferable transferable = new Transferable() {
            @Override
            public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
                return new DataFlavor[] {DataFlavor.imageFlavor, DataFlavor.stringFlavor};
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public @NotNull Object getTransferData(DataFlavor dataFlavor) {
                if(dataFlavor.equals(DataFlavor.imageFlavor)) {
                    return image;
                } else if(dataFlavor.equals(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
                    return text;
                }
                return image;
            }
        };
        
        clipboard.setContents(transferable, null);
    }
}
```

and i got these outputs:

```
java.io.IOException: Registered service providers failed to encode BufferedImage@6108b2d7: type = 6 ColorModel: #pixelBits = 32 numComponents = 4 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@246ae04d transparency = 3 has alpha = true isAlphaPre = false ByteInterleavedRaster: width = 32 height = 33 #numDataElements 4 dataOff[0] = 3 to image/jpeg
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.datatransfer.DataTransferer.imageToStandardBytesImpl(DataTransferer.java:1802)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.datatransfer.DataTransferer.imageToStandardBytes(DataTransferer.java:1716)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.windows.WDataTransferer.imageToPlatformBytes(WDataTransferer.java:353)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.datatransfer.DataTransferer.translateTransferable(DataTransferer.java:855)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.windows.WDataTransferer.translateTransferable(WDataTransferer.java:220)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.windows.WClipboard.setContentsNative(WClipboard.java:83)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.datatransfer.SunClipboard.setContents(SunClipboard.java:105)
    at ClipboardTest.main(ClipboardTest.java:41)

进程已结束，退出代码为 0
```

Comment: I suspect the exception occurred in the last line of your `getTransferData` method.  If the DataFlavor is neither image nor string, do not just assume it’s okay to return the image.  The last line of that method should be `throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(dataFlavor);` and should not contain a `return` statement at all.  See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.datatransfer/java/awt/datatransfer/Transferable.html#getTransferData(java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor)) for details.